# NetworkOnMainThread with Scheduler.io()

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-android, rx-java2

I have tried using Scheduler.newThread() and Scheduler.io() but still no luck
Here is my code

```
Observable<Response> loginObservable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<Response> emitter) throws Exception {

                btSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if(validateFields()) {

                           // progressDialog.show();

                            Configs configs = new Configs(LoginActivity.this);
                            String versionName = new AppUtils(LoginActivity.this).getVersionName();

                            credentials.setGrantType(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD);
                            credentials.setUserName(username.getText().toString().trim());
                            credentials.setPassword(password.getText().toString());
                            credentials.setAppId(configs.getValue(APP_ID));
                            credentials.setOs(Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields()[Build.VERSION.SDK_INT].getName());
                            credentials.setBrowser(versionName);

                            // TODO: 05-Jul-17 get device type programmatically
                            credentials.setDevice("Tablet");

                            httpAuth = new HttpAuth.Builder()
                                    .setBaseUrl(configs.getValue(BASE_URL))
                                    .setCredentials(credentials)
                                    .build();
                           // ** This is network request**
                            Response response = httpAuth.loginToken("Token", TOKEN_NEW);

                            emitter.onNext(response);
                            emitter.onComplete();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This is how i am subscribing

```
loginObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

                .subscribe(observer);
```

Getting *android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException* at this `Response response = httpAuth.loginToken("Token", TOKEN_NEW);`

Please help.

Comment: Any body else wanna answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only set the `onClickListener` to the button in the `Schedulers.newThread()`, but the code performed inside `onClick` is run on the main thread. That is the reason of the exception.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds right. Please suggest a way i don't wanna create another thread as it will kill the purpose of using schedulers.

Comment: @eCDroid, I'll edit my answer to show how I think it should be

Comment: @eCDroid, ok, I'm not enough familiar with RxJava to show you how should it be, but you should do the subscription inside the onclick. So you basically click the button, and then it subscribes and does the network operations.

Comment: Isn't this will be redundant to subscribe the observer for every click? Anyway thanks for the answer and suggestions :)

Comment: @eCDroid, unfortunately don't know how to implement it correctly. Not good with Rxjava enought

Comment: No worries. Let's wait for some one else to answer and see. I'm also struggling hard with Rx-Android :{

Answer (score 1):

When you subscribe to your `Observable` you are just setting a clickListener to your `Button`. What you should do is to create a logic like this:

```
btSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
        getLoginObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(observer);
    }
}



Observable<Response> getLoginObservable() {
    return new ObservableOnSubscribe<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<Response> emitter) throws Exception {
             // create your request
             Response response = httpAuth.loginToken("Token", TOKEN_NEW);

             emitter.onNext(response);
             emitter.onComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like that much this approach, because it feels like you are breaking the reactive paradigm. So another option is to bound your flow directly to the click event. You can do it manually or you can relay on a good library (from Jake Wharton) [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding). With this library you can create an `Observable` that emits item associated with the click events. Then you can connect this `Observable` with your "stream", for example using `flatMap` operator.

```
RxView.clicks(btSignin) // this creates an Observable
```

Another good tip is to use `Retrofit` for network request. In this way you can Obtain directly an `Observable` that emits the response.

Comment: ain't it redundant and expensive to create a new observable and subscribe it every time on button click?

Comment: It is not a big problem. But as I said this is why I don't like it that much. With RxBinding you create an `Observable` from your click event and you transform that event into something else with `map` or `flatMap` in order to execute other operations, like network calls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer